# Value not displayed after losing focus on form.textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, celleditorlistener

I have a custom grid and some cells have a cell editor , an Ext.form.TextField,  in order to modify value of the cell.
Here is how is defined the TextField:

```
var labelTextEditor = new Ext.form.TextField({
    allowBlank: false,
    maxLength: 256,
    id: "labelTextEditor",
    maxLengthText: Label.conf.ui.javascript.TooLongText,
    validateOnChange: true,
    validator: function(value) {
        console.log(value);
        if (value == "" && value.trim() == "") {
            return formatMessage(Label.conf.ui.supv.LabelMandatory);
        } else
            return true;
    },
    msgTarget: 'under',
    listeners: {
        focus( a, event, eOpts ){
            var rowIndex = customFieldGrid.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition().row;
            if(rowIndex !== undefined && rowIndex !== null){
                a.setValue(view.listOfServiceDefinition[0].customFields[rowIndex].labels[userLanguagePrefix]);
            }
        },
        blur(a, event, eOpts){
            var cellValue = a.getValue();
            if(cellValue !== undefined && cellValue !== null){
                a.setValue(cellValue);
            }else{
                a.setValue("");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When I focus on the cell, it keeps me the value that was there before focusing on the cell, thanks to the focus listener. But when I lose focus, the cell displays nothing. When I click back on it, the value is displayed again and can be edited. So the problem is that when I lose focus, the value cannot be kept displayed on the cell. I've tried to blur event but didn't help...

Answer (score 2):

Problem here is your `blur` event. As Per  [Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.form.field.Text.html) **blur event Fires when this Component loses focus.** So in your case  when you loosing focus your blur event is firing. And As I can see in your blur event You are setting some other values, Therefor it is coming as empty.

This line is causing an issue in your code :

```
else{
     a.setValue("");
    }
```

I also created one fiddler to understand `blur` and `focus`.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1su3)